# What is the best call DOM control javascript function in each example.html file(example.blade.php) or common.js?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

For Example, in one project, there are many example*.html(example*.blade.php)

- common.js

```js
var common = {
    movingTest : function(){
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click',
        function(){
           //something to move Test
        }
        );
    }
}
```

1. case 1. call in each file.

(FOR EXAMPLE, example1, example3, example5 have id="test" but not example2, example4, example6)

- example1.html(example1.blade.php)

```html
<html>
<body>
// This id="test" is not included in every example*.html(example*.blade.php)
<div id="test"></div>
<script src="common.js"></script>
<script>
    common.movingTest();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

2. case 2. call in common.js

```js
var common = {
    movingTest : function(){
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click',
        function(){
           //something to move Test
        }
        );
    },
} 

// there are not every test in .html file, i wrote "if"
if(document.getElementById("test").length !== 0){
    common.movingTest();
}
```

what is the be practice?
or can i detect what is the best through any other tools?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Case 1 is generally the best practice for including sensitive javascript files as they reside outside your html file.

Case 2 is not recommended generally and is not a best practice due to security concerns. And also it affects the page load speeds if the js file is too big.

So case 1 is best, always include your js file instead of hardcoding them in you html file.